# How can I watch a specific path?

Tags: c, freebsd

Is it possible to 'watch' a specifc path and have the kernel notify me whenever a file or directory of that *name* is deleted / written / read / created / etc.?

Note: I am looking for an answer in C.  I will accept an answer that points me to the underlying implementation in a different language though (provided I could find the C code)

Comment: See: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26528/C-Application-to-Watch-a-File-or-Directory-using-F

Comment: @MeysamTolouee that seems like a windows centric answer of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe this help: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/KernelQueues/KernelQueues.html

Comment: in BSD, kqueue.  in linux, inotify.   or you can use glib's wrapper in gio which also does win32 but has a lgpl2 license.

Comment: @technosaurus good to know; unfortunately I am limited only to free software but I could see what APIs glib uses.

Comment: LGPL2 is pretty free...

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the kernel supports `inotify`, which allows monitoring of specific files and directories.  It appears that a similar thing is available for FreeBSD called [`pnotify`](http://pnotify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README) which was based on the Linux 'inotify' interface. (I have used inotify; however, I have not used pnotify myself).

inotify does not require you to write a kernel module.  All APIs are available in user-space. Once properly initialized, your application simply calls `read()` with an inotify file descriptor to monitor file and/or directory activity.  The read events come in a structure:

```
struct inotify_event    
   {
   int      wd;       /* Watch descriptor */
   uint32_t mask;     /* Mask of events */
   uint32_t cookie;   /* Unique cookie associating related events */
   uint32_t len;      /* Size of name field */
   char     name[];   /* Optional null-terminated name */
   };
```

From what I have read of pnotify, it is very similar.

Comment: Your link is to the SUSE man page, not a FreeBSD man page.  This answer uses an API which does not exist in FreeBSD.

Comment: I think that FreeBSD just has the option to view other project's man pages.  Check the dropdown: it has netbsd, openbsd, multiple versions of SUSE, etc.

Comment: Ok, I think my answer is better now. pnotify url:http://pnotify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the kqueue interface.  inotify does not exist on FreeBSD.

kqueue came first and is generally considered a better interface.